# What is the better way to build multi_app

Tags: android, performance

I've been wondering what was the better way to build a multi-window android app:

- Display each window in a different activity.
- Keep the same activity and inflate and remove views.

It seems clear to me that it depends on the nature of the application, so let's take for instance an app that has to be launched only from the main Activity and that was not designed to receive implicit intents and to communicate with other applications.

The reason I am asking is that it appears to me that removing views and adding inflated ones is faster as you do not need to lunch another activity. But I wonder if there is some underlying drawbacks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastest way is to use one main activity for the app and then open fragments for other views. So let's say when you open your application you have first you open the `MainActivity` and if you have buttons in the activity and want on click of the button another view (window) to be opened. That can be made using fragments. In the main activity state

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.name_of_the_frame_layout, nameOfTheFragmentClass)
                        .commit();
```

With this code you can open the stated fragment. For that create a class that extends Fragment. `.addToBackStack(null)` this is used only if you don't want on back clicked to go to previous fragment. In the main activity the best practice is to have a `FrameLayout` where the fragments will be put and replaced.

And all in all you can't go wrong with using fragments as they are the best practice to go to unless you specifically have to use activities.

Comment: Hi Clair, thanks for the explanation. That's pretty clear

Comment: Can you confirm the answer if it is what you are looking for, so it can be closed.

Comment: The answer was clear and helpful. But I wish I had different ones for the simple reason that the more I get the more enlightening it would be :)